# Limit to 2 decimals in TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The code below works fine but, in the textbox the decimal value has this format "0,0000" 
(, is the decimal separator). I'd like have only 2 decimal. How can I do this ?

Thanks,

```
//Database model used with NHibernate
public class Bank
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName{ get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

//MVC Model
public class MyModel
{
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }  
}

//View
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bank.Amount, new { id = "tbAmount"})
```

### Update 1

In the debugger, I don't see any decimal, wehn I do step by step inside (o @HTML.Textbofor) the view, the value does not have any decimal but when the page is displayed there are 4 decimals

```
//Database model used with NHibernate
public class Bank
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName{ get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

//Class for view
public class ViewBank
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

//MVC Model
public class MyModel
{
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }      
    var ViewBank = new ViewBank() { Amount = Bank.Amount};
}

//View
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { id = "tbAmount"})
```

Comment: What MVC version are you using?

Comment: It's strange, for me Html.TextBoxFor() is rendered without zeros at all for decimal and int properties.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I would use editor templates and I would **not** use my NHibernate domain models in my views. I would define view models which are specifically tailored to the requirements of the given view (in this case limiting the amount to 2 decimals):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bank.Amount)
```

Comment: If you not use  NHibernate domaine model in View, that's means you have to create a specific class for the view with the same properties (the property you use in the view) ?

Comment: @Kris-I, yes you need to create a view model for each view. And it is not with the same properties. Only the properties used by this specific view and also containing the necessary formatting and validation attributes for this specific view.

Comment: You tried but not work or do somehting wrong ... see my update1

Comment: @Kris-I, what doesn't work? When I run your example the Amount is formatted with 2 digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: @Darin yes :) In the example project that's work no in my real proejct. I have to check why. Could you valid the example is the good way ?

Comment: @Kris-I, yes the example seems correct to me. Ensure that in your real project you are using `EditorFor` in the view (instead of `TextBoxFor`) and that the property you are passing as lambda expression to this EditorFor is decorated with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute.

Comment: I'm using TextBoxFor because I need to pass htmlAttributes (width).  EditorFor does not have htmlAttributes.  How do you control both the width and the decimal places in an edit box? Thanks

Comment: I've posted this a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927811/how-to-control-both-the-width-and-decimal-places-for-a-text-box

Answer (score 41):

This works for me

```
@Html.TextBox("Amount", String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.Bank.Amount), new { id = "tbAmount"})
```

**EDIT:**

This is for TextBoxFor (does not work on MVC3)

```
@{var formated = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.Bank.Amount);}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bank.Amount, formated, new { id = "tbAmount"})
```

Comment: This requires you to manually input the textbox names. TextBoxFor() automatically takes care of the input field's id, name and value. I'm not saying your answer is not a solution, but I would expect there to be a way in which you can preserve the usage of TextBoxFor(). Still looking for it myself though :-)

Comment: Your "TextBoxFor" example doesn't use TextboxFor.

Comment: This really is the most convenient way if you have additional HTML attributes to apply since there is no such overload to EditorFor.  Otherwise, you'd likely need named decimal editor templates that know how to make use of your view data as attributes.

Comment: Not sure how this is working,  as when I have tried to employ the code in the EDIT section above I got the following error:
"error CS1501: No overload for method 'TextBoxFor' takes 3 arguments"

Comment: the overload of TextBoxFor you are using is the MVC4 one. If you have not registered the MVC 4 assembly **this will not work in MVC3**

Comment: you are right. i tested it on an MVC4 app which I thought was MVC3. sorry

Comment: This is the only answer that works for me. Darin Dimitrov's answer "{0:n2}" adds a comma thousands separator to the value of my number-type input, which causes it to be blank.

Answer (score 24):

In MVC 4 you can now pass the format as the second parameter

```
//View
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bank.Amount, "{0:n2}", new { id = "tbAmount"})
```

Comment: This seems like the quickest answer I could find. Kudos.

Comment: I originally thought this worked, but a couple of weeks on I am finding that it adds a comma thousands separator that to the value of my number-type input,  which causes it to be blank. Alexandros answer above is the only one that works for me (0:0.00) without any edge-cases. Also, stackoverflow has decided that I am not allowed to change my mind and that I shouldn't be able to remove my upvote on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have customized editor template for `Decimal` type then `EditorFor` decorated with `DisplayFormatAttribute` would probably work out of the box.

For a custom editor template I ended up using something like:

```
@model decimal?

@{
    string displayValue;
    if (Model == null)
    {
        displayValue = null;
    }
    else {
        var formatString = (ViewData.ModelMetadata).DisplayFormatString;
        displayValue = formatString == null ? Model.ToString() : string.Format(formatString, Model);
    }

}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c, new { type = "text", Value = displayValue, @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c)
</div>
```

Which works when the property is decorated with `DisplayFormatAttribute` like so:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n1}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Commission")]
public decimal? CommissionPercentage { get; set; }
```

Comment: Move the code formatting decimal? to extension method and voila: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { Value = Model.ToPrice() })

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

in MVC5, in View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Amount, "{0:n0}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Output before StringFormatting --> 15000.00

Output after StringFormatting --> 15000