# How to round off value in MVC 4 into to two decimal places.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

What I need is if 5000 ----> 5000.00
               if 5000.985 ----> 5000.99

always there should be a two decimal places.

This is my model class.

```
    [Display(Name = "Price (Rs.)")]
    public double price { get; set; }
```

This is my cshtml page (View).

```
        <div class="display-label">
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do this with an annotation.

```cs
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121625/4972749) for more information

Comment: Thank you very much @Luuk Moret. Your answer is really helpful. And it is working. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="display-label">
      @Math.Round(model=>model.price, 2)
</div>
```

and you'd better use "decimal" not "double"